# Java Web Start application with a configuration directory

Tags: java, configuration, java-web-start

I have a java application which is packed into an executable jar file and it uses it's own conf directory to store some configuration options.

Now I want to distribute it as a Java Web Start application. I know that I could pack the configuration files in the distributed jar but it should cause some significant changes in application logic.

So is there a standard way or a simple workaround for the configuration directory distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration options for a rich client deployed using JWS are probably best stored in the [`PersistenceService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/PersistenceService.html).